# Check version of OS then issue a command if the correct version

Tags: macos, bash, operating-system, osx-lion, sh

i am writing a bash script for Mac OS X Lion 10.7 and i would like to know how i can check the version of the OS in bash and if the version is lets say 10.7.1 then it does a command and continues with the script and do the same thing for a different version lets say 10.7.3 then it does a different command then the command that used for 10.7.1?

Answer (score 9):

**OS_Version (full… example 10.7.3)**

```
system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType | grep "System Version" | awk '{print $6}'
```

OR

```
sw_vers -productVersion
```

**OS (short… example 10.7)**

```
system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType | grep "System Version" | awk '{print $6}' | sed "s:.[[:digit:]]*.$::g"
```

OR

```
OS_Version=$(OS (short… example 10.7) | sed "s:.[[:digit:]]*)
```

**bash:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Use one of the examples given above to create the OS_Version variable

if [[ ${OS_Version} == 10.7.3 ]]; then
   echo "Operating System is a match... will continue on."
else
   echo "Operating System is NOT a match... will NOT continue."
fi
```

Comment: I had to use $5 instead of $6.

Comment: `sw_vers -productVersion` should arguably be the first answer.  From experience as well as reading the comments, it avoids having to worry about `$5` versus `$6` and it is more scalable

Comment: How would you check `if [[ ${OS_Version} >= 10.7.3 ]];`?

Answer (score 7):

You want the `sw_vers` command on OS X. It prints some human-readable strings, including the 10.X.X system version (`sw_vers -productVersion`). You can also use `uname` to check the kernel version; if your script is ever ported to other Unix variants `uname` will work there.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to check the major OS version, keep in mind the Darwin version corresponds to it, and within bash is set to a shell variable that is easy to coerce to a numerically comparable integer.

```
if [[ ${OSTYPE:6} -ge 13 ]]; then
    echo "At least 10.9, so feeling fine.";
else 
    echo "Time to put the old cat to sleep.";
fi
```